# How to get the position (index in order) of an XML element using LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, silverlight-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have XML exactly like this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book>
    <chapter>
        <verse>This is verse 1</verse>
        <verse>This is verse 2</verse>
        <verse>This is verse 3</verse>
        <verse>This is verse 4</verse>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <verse>This is verse 1</verse>
        <verse>This is verse 2</verse>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <verse>This is verse 1</verse>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

In C# using Linq, I need to be able to get the XML element of a specific position or index, based on the value of the function state.getChapterNumber(). For example, if the value were 4, I need to grab the 4th chapter element from the XML document.

```
XDocument book = XDocument.Load(string.Format("Translations/NWT/{0}.xml", state.BookName));
var verses = from chapter in book.Decendants()
             where state.getChapterNumber() == (WHAT DO I PUT HERE TO MATCH THE VALUE??)
             from verse in chapter.Descendants("p").Elements()
             select new
             {
                 VerseNumber = verse.Attribute("n").Value,
                 Text = verse.Value,
                 LastVerseInParagraph = verse.Parent.Elements().LastOrDefault().Value,
                 FirstVerseInParagraph = verse.Parent.Elements().FirstOrDefault().Value
             };
```

Please help, this is really important and has been holding me back for days. All I want to do is be able to get verses from any chapter set that I choose in the book.

Comment: Why can I not say `where chapter.Index().Value == state.getChapterNumber()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well to start with, I don't think you wanted the second descendant overall - you wanted the second *chapter*, which isn't necessarily the same thing. Fortunately it's easy to do:

```
// Use 1 for the second chapter, 2 for "element 2" (i.e. the third element) etc
var chapter = book.Descendants("chapter").ElementAt(1);

var verses = from verse in chapter...
```

EDIT: For the verse number, use the overload of `Select` which provides the element index:

```
var verses = chapter.Element("verse")
                    .Select((element, index) => new {
                                VerseNumber = index + 1,
                                Text = element.Value
                            });
```

I don't think it makes much sense for *every* verse to have the first and last verse in the paragraph, personally. It's not really a feature of that verse, is it?

Comment: You simple programming technique helped too. Maybe you can help figure out how I can get linq to return the iteration count for each `select new` So I would have `VerseNumber = THE ITERATION,` instead of the line above. Would I write something like `VerseNumber = verse.Index().Value,`

Comment: My friend, you saved my life! I'm making a celebratory drink right now! Here is what I did (all thanks to you). I made a class called `Verse` that contained all my variables. And I then used your technique like this. `var verses = book.Descendants("c").ElementAt(state.GetChapter() - 1).Descendants("p").Elements()
                    .Select((element, index) => new Verse
                    {
                        VerseNumber = (index + 1).ToString(),
                        ScriptureText = element.Value
                    });` This worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: If I may ask you too, is there a way to convert that to a linq sql? How would you write the overload of the select? In other words, how would you write this `Select((element, index) => new Verse { element, index });` in the linq sql format?

Comment: @GuyMicciche: By "the LINQ SQL format" I assume you mean as a query expression? (`from x in y where x.foo select x.bar`?) There's no support for this overload in query expression syntax.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have a simmilar case, but for me, the verses are unique, how can I be able to get the index of the chapter?

Comment: @DennysHenry: I'm not sure what you mean by that, to be honest. You may well be better off asking a new question, with a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the feedback, find the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531837/looping-xml-from-a-specific-node)

Answer (score 2):

Another correct answer, although Jon Skeet's answer is way more efficient, is this code:

```
chapter.ElementsBeforeSelf().Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the extension method notation you can use the `Select()` call that will provide you the index of the current element like this:

```
var indexedChapters = book.Decendants().Select((Chapter, Index) => new { Chapter, Index });
```

Afterwards you can than access the index of the anonymous type in any following linq statement.

Comment: In my linq statement after the 'from' statement, my where statement looks like this: `where book.Decendants("c").Index == state.GetChapterNumber()` Basically, I'm pulling a value from a function to get the corresponding xml element position based on that value. Can you help, it seems you have me in the right direction.

Comment: I have a bigger problem. Where I have `VerseNumber = verse.Attribute("n").Value,` I need the VerseNumber value each time to iterate through the number of verses in the XML file per chapter. Oh boy.