# Looping XML from a specific node

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an XML File, say

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sqldiff version="1.0">
    <diff>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <sql>
            CODE HERE
        </sql>
    </diff>

    <diff>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <sql>
            CODE HERE
        </sql>
    </diff>
</sqldiff>
```

I am storing the version of the last diff that was executed (In this case 1.0.1). I don't want to loop through the entire XML file every time the application runs, instead, just checks if any new diffs (in this case I can get the version from the last diff).

My problem is that, I don't want to loop through the entire XML to comparing versions, to know which ones to skip and which ones to execute.

Currently, am looping through all diffs and comparing the versions, untill it gets a newer version, it executes that, then stores the last diff executed. Here is my code:

```
        Dim BaseVersion = New Version(GetLastVersion()) 'Eg. returns 1.0.2

        Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
        xmlDoc.Load("D:\sqldiff.xml")
        Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/sqldiff/diff")
        Dim pID As String = "", pCode As String = ""
        For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
            pID = node.SelectSingleNode("version").InnerText
            pCode = node.SelectSingleNode("sql").InnerText

            'Checks if pID>BaseVersion Then Executes code and store current pID
            'Else Continue
        Next
```

Comment: Replace following : For Each node As XmlNode In nodes; For  i = nodes.Count - 1 to 0 step -1 then node = nodes(i)

Comment: @jdweng how can I find the index of an element (node) with `<version>1.0.1</version>` so that I can loop from that index `for i=<indexOfVersion1.0.1> to nodes.Count-1`. Also note the version is passed as a parameter, it will not always be the same

Comment: Try something like this :  Dim ver As XmlNode = nodes.Cast(Of XmlNode).Where(Function(x) x.SelectSingleNode("version").Value = "1.0.0").FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @jdweng this looks like a neat approach, however, `ver` returns `Nothing`while I have version 1.0.0 Changing that to 1.0.1 still returns `Nothing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Looking for a while and not finding any similar solutions to what I was looking for I tried a couple of methods and finally got it working. [This Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531837/looping-xml-from-a-specific-node/41532380#41532380) by [dbasnett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66532/dbasnett) was instrumental to me fixing this problem.

First I get the sqldiff.xml file

```
Dim xe As System.Xml.Linq.XElement
xe = XElement.Load(IO.Path.Combine(yourpath, "sqldiff.xml"))
```

Next I get the Last element (Thanks to [dbasnett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66532/dbasnett))

```
Dim lastVersEL As XElement = xe...<version>.LastOrDefault
```

Lastly, I use `lastVersEL` and compare it to `baseVersion` from the Original Question, and if `lastVersEL` is greater, it means there are new diffs added, and the I use the code below to get the XElement of the passed version

```
Dim lastExecutedEL As XElement = (From c In xe...<version> Where c.Value = baseVersion Select c).SingleOrDefault()
```

And To get the index (THE SOLUTION I WAS LOOKING FOR)

```
Dim index As Integer = xe...<version>.Nodes.ToArray.ToList.IndexOf(lastExecutedEL.FirstNode)
```

And then I proceeded to loop and execute the diffs as per the code below

```
       If lastVersEL > baseVersion Then
           Dim lastExecutedEL As XElement = (From c In xe...<version> Where c.Value = baseVersion Select c).SingleOrDefault()
           Dim index As Integer = xe...<version>.Nodes.ToArray.ToList.IndexOf(lastExecutedEL.FirstNode)

           For i As Integer = index To xe...<version>.Nodes.Count
             'Executes the SQL stored in the Elements by gettings the value as below
             'elements(i).Parent.<sql>.Value.Trim

           Next

        End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question was a little confusing because the xml doesn't seem to match the code provided, i.e. the reference to Product_name in the code.

As far as getting the last version node and checking against a new version then something like this should work,

```
Public Function NewDiff(newVers As String) As String
    'Dim yourpath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    'yourpath = IO.Path.Combine(yourpath, "test.xml")

    Dim xe As XElement
    ' to load from a file
    'xe = XElement.Load(yourpath)
    ' for testing
    xe = <sqldiff version="1.0">
             <diff>
                 <version>1.0.0</version>
                 <sql>
                     <!-- CODE HERE -->
                     foo
                 </sql>
             </diff>

             <diff>
                 <version>1.0.1</version>
                 <sql>
                     <!-- CODE HERE -->
                     bar
                 </sql>
             </diff>
         </sqldiff>

    Dim rv As String = Nothing
    Dim lastVersEL As XElement = xe...<version>.LastOrDefault
    If lastVersEL.Value <> newVers Then
        'get the sql nodes value for the selected version
        rv = lastVersEL.Parent.<sql>.Value.Trim
        Stop
    End If
    ' to save file
    ' xe.Save(yourpath)
    Return rv
End Function
```

Tested like this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim s As String = NewDiff("1.0.2")
End Sub
```

If you need to check to see if the new version exists within the xml because the new versions may not be passed in order then minor changes would need to be made.

Comment: Apologies for that. I have corrected that. Also, kindly explain how you are able to get a compare on this line
`Dim lastVersEL As XElement = xe...<version>.LastOrDefault`

Comment: @DennysHenry - that line gets the last version nodes value.The next line does the compare.

Comment: @DennysHenry - edited the code above to return the sql nodes value for the selected version.

Comment: I have a line like this
`Dim LastNodeVersion As Version = New Version(nodes(nodes.Count - 1).SelectSingleNode("version").InnerText)`
This gets the last node, to determine if any diffs were added. 
But the problem, if any diffs were added, I have to loop through all the diffs to get to the latest diff, then start executing the code from there (could be the grow to thousands). Is there a way I can get the position of the last diff version executed, then loop from that?

Comment: @DennysHenry - I am confused because I don't understand the relationship between the various node types and their usage.

Comment: sorry maybe my question was not clear, when the system processes the diffs, it records the last diff version that was processed, e.g 1.0.3. When diffs are added, they have an auto increment number, 1.0.4, etc. On processing the diffs, it checks if any diffs were added since the last diff, and if any, it loops through the diffs. 
My problem currently, is that I have to loop through all of them to find the new ones.
Is there a way I can get an index of say `<version>1.0.3</version>` then now i can use:

    `For i=<index of last processed diff> to nodes.Count-1
    'Process diffs
    Next`

Comment: @DennysHenry - you didn't answer my questions.  Edit your original question to show the xml before and after and describe the nodes and what they mean please.

Comment: This is a node

```<diff>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<sql>
<!-- CODE HERE -->
 foo
</sql>
</diff>```

The next one is also a node, from the original xml, it will return two nodes, one whose version is 1.0.1 and another with 1.0.2